# qmail received email's removed attachment recovery

Tags: email

I"m using qmail+vpopmail+spamassassin+simcontrol.
I've received an email but the attachment has been removed. How can i recover that removed attachment and where can i search it. Any help please?

in /var/qmail/control there is nothing in simcontrol file.

Answer (score 0):

Check /var/qmail/control for the spamassassin/simcontrol configuration files.  They should tell you where things are being quarantined.